# mat-form-field required field is showing red asterik even if there is no error in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Iam facing the issue that mat-form-field required asterik even if there is no error. I would like to show blue asterik if there is no error. I have spent a lot of time but I am not able to fogure it out. If anyone knows what is wrong then please let me know. Thank you

```html
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="input-field-large input-normal-wide" matInput>
                    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                    <input
                        (input)="onNameChange()"
                        formControlName="name"
                        type="text"
                        autocomplete="off"
                        matInput
                        maxlength="50"
                        required="required"
                    />
                    <mat-icon
                        *ngIf="form.hasError('required', 'name') && isNameSubmitted"
                        class="mdi mdi-24px mdi-alert-circle"
                        matSuffix
                    >
                    </mat-icon>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('required', 'name') && isNameSubmitted">
                        <span>{{ "This field is mandatory" | translate }}</span>
                    </mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('maxlength', 'name') && isNameSubmitted">
                        <span>{{ "Maximum 50 charachers are allowed" | translate }}</span>
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: you can use `[required]="form.hasError('required','name')?true:null"`. See that when we want an attribute true or remove the attribute we use the way [attribute]="condition?true:null" -it's important the "null". NOTE: you should **remove** the `matInput` to the "mat-form-field" tag, matInput is applied to an Input.

Comment: @Eliseo  I would like to show blue asterik if there is no error.

Comment: Sorry my bad quick reading way. If you want change the color you need override the .css `.mat-focused .mat-form-field-required-marker`, see my answer (and Yes, I've never understand the red * when is valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as follow:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused {
    .mat-form-field-required-marker {
        color: blue;
    }
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid {
    .mat-form-field-required-marker {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color of the "*", add this .css to your "styles.css" (not in the component.css)

```
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-required-marker
{
  color:blue
}
.ng-invalid.ng-touched.mat-focused .mat-form-field-required-marker
{
  color:red
}
```

In only want to hide the "*" you use

```
[required]="form.hasError('required','name')?true:null"
```

See [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tnhk9-hjzfqx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a form field with `formControlName` directive i guess you have a formGroup, if you just want to make sure the input has a value don't use `required` directly on the template, instead use `Validators` in the .ts file of your component.

For example:

```
public myFormGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
})
```

In the FormControl constructor you can pass, as the second parameter, a validator function or an array of validator functions. The required function is one of them, addional pre-defined validators are:

- max
- min
- not-null
- pattern(for regex validations)

and more.

You can also define a custom function if you need it tho

Comment: I am using validator functions but I am using required in template because I have to show asterik in the field. With out using required asterik is not appearing in the field

Comment: what do you mean with "show asterisk **in** the field"? Can you edit your question to show what you're trying to achieve?